# What is wrong with use of lambda here

Tags: scala, lambda

I wrote `map1` function similar to `List.map` as:

```
def map1[A, B](xs: List[A], f: A => B): List[B] = {
  xs match {
    case List() => scala.collection.immutable.Nil
    case head :: tail => f(head) :: map1(tail, f)
  }
}
```

Now when I call the above as:

```
map1(List(1, 2, 3), x => x + 1)
```

I get error as: `error: missing parameter type`. But following works:

```
List(1, 2, 3).map(x => x + 1)
```

Why `map1` doesn't work with lamdas?

Comment: It's not a lambda issue since this works `(x:Int)=>x+1`. It's an issue with the type inference engine.

Comment: Inference issue: type `A` can be inferred for `f` from `xs` as in the same parameter list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scala, argument type inference works between argument lists and not inside them. To help the compiler infer the type, move `f` to it's own argument list:

```
def map1[A, B](xs: List[A])(f: A => B): List[B] = {
  xs match {
    case Nil => scala.collection.immutable.Nil
    case head :: tail => f(head) :: map1(tail)(f)
  }
}
```